# Getting an error in Task<FindItemsResults<Item>> does not contain definition

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on retrieve the mail from outlook 365 using C#. I am getting an error in the below code.

```
var findResults = _service.FindItems(WellknownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(10));

var eItems = findResults.Items.Case<EmailMessage>(); --> Debugger is showing an Error in the "Items"
```

> Error : 'Task<FindItemsResults>' does not contain a defintion for 'Items' and no accessible extension method 'Items' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<FindItemsResults>'  could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am trying so many ways. But still getting the above error. Can you please suggest on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean to `await` the call to `_service.FindItems`?

Comment: Try and remember to name your `async`/`Task`-returning methods with `...Async` on the end of the name. It helps remind you to `await` them: `var r = x.DoSomethingAsync(...)` should thus (come to) *look wrong* to you -> `r` is the Task itself, not the result of the Task.

Comment: The other thing you can do to get a spidey sense for whan you've walked into this trap is quite simple: any time you see a compiler message of *Task<...> does not contain a definition for X* it probably means you've forgotten an `await` or other mechanism to let the Task complete and get the result you want; you're trying to access X which is a property of the result object, not a property of the Task that will eventually deliver the result

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've installed something like NuGet package `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.NETStandard` by sherlock1982, rather than `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices` by Microsoft; the latter has a FindItems that runs syncronously

`FindItems` in the lib you're using is asyncronous, using the task async pattern. This means `Finditems` returns a `Task<FindItemsResults<Item>>` rather than a `FindItemsResults<Item>`. The Task represents a background operation that will soon deliver the result you want. To get the result, you have to `await` for the `Task` to finish.. WHile you're awaiting, the thread that is executing your code will go off and find something else to do, so it's not just sitting around idle

It's not difficult to get the result from the Task:

```
var findResults = await _service.FindItems(WellknownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(10));
                  ^^^^^
           this essentially turns a Task<X> into an X
```

..but it does mean that the method that this call is in needs to be marked `async` and have its return type changed from `WhateverItIsNow` to `Task<WhateverItIsNow>`..

..which means that any method that calls *that method* must also be changed in the same way, which means..

and so on all the way up the call chain and out of your code..

It is this way because that's how TAP works; it effectively provides a route for the thread that is executing your code to pause what it's doing to your code and escape back to wherever it came from, so it can go and find some other work to do while it waits for O365 to deliver on the results of the search

If your code looked like this before:

```
static void Main(){
  var r = GetItems();
}

static Something GetItems(){
  var findResults = _service.FindItems(WellknownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(10));

  var eItems = findResults.Items.Case<EmailMessage>();

  return blahblah;

}
```

You'll need to tweak it to look like this now:

```
static async Task Main(){                        //void -> async Task
  var r = await GetItemsAsync();
}

static async Task<Something> GetItemsAsync(){    //Something -> async Task<Something>, and also rename to add ...Async
  var findResults = await _service.FindItems(WellknownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(10));

  var eItems = findResults.Items.Case<EmailMessage>();

  return blahblah;

}
```

Simple rules of thumb to get started with TAP:

- A method that has `await` in the body needs to be changed so it:

  - is `async Task` now if it was `void` before or,
  - is `async Task<Thing>` now if it returned `Thing` before
  - and is named `..Async(`
- The method that called it like `SomeMethod()` before now needs to call it like `await SomeMethodAsync()`
- Propagate that all the way up your entire code call stack

You get a special pass in Windows Forms event handlers - they're allowed to use `async void` like `async void SomeButton_Click(obejct sender, EventArgs e)` but don't write `async void` at other times; `async Task` only - `async void` is a big can of worms